# Convert Json cURL command to Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, curl

I'm working on some curl command api and I want to convert them to javascript. Where can I learn how to convert them to javascript?

```
curl -v -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json"
-H "Accept: application/json" -X PUT --user myusername:mypassword
https[..to a specific location..] -d 
"{\"name\": \"Marcus0.1\",\"start\": 500000,\"end\": 1361640526000}"
```

Thanks

Comment: What kind of Javascript request? Server-side? Client-side? AJAX? Can you post some code for what you've tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this in Javascript depending on the environment. At a higher level, here's what that curl command is doing.

- Using the HTTP PUT method
- Setting a `Content-Type` header to `application/json`
- Adding a `Authorization` header for the username and password specified (see [Client side here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) for more details on the wire format)
- Setting the request body to the JSON specified after the `-d` parameter
- Sending that all to the URL specified